# Добавление значение в input через кнопки

Tags: jquery, input

```js
var balance = 3000; // доступный баланс
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="bet-sum">
<div class="buttons">
  <button type="submit">+10</button>
  <button type="submit">+100</button>
  <button type="submit">+1k</button>
  <button type="submit">1/2 (разделить на 2)</button>
  <button type="submit">x2 (умножить на 2)</button>
  <button type="submit">all (весь баланс (var balance))</button>
</div>
```

Как правильно и красиво реализовать функцию прибавления значение в input с помощью Jquery.

мое решение:

```
function updateBalance(data) {
  var input_val = $("bet-sum").val();
  switch(data) {
    case "x2": input_val * 2;
    break;
    case "+100": input_val + 100;
    break;
    case "+1k": input_val + 100;
    break;
    case "1/2": input_val / 2;
    break;
    case "all": input_val = balance;
    break;
    default: input_val = input_val;
  }
}
```

можно ли его как-то улучшить?

Answer (score 0):

Можно хранить вспомогательную информацию в [`data`-атрибутах](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) и использовать её для выбора операции.

```js
let buttons = document.getElementById('buttons');
let balance = document.getElementById('balance');
buttons.addEventListener('click', updateBalance);

const functions = {
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
  '=': (a, b) => b,
};

function updateBalance(event) {
  let button = event.target;
  if (button.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'button')
    return;
  
  let currentBalance = +balance.value
  let func = functions[button.dataset.function];
  let parameter = +button.dataset.parameter;
  balance.value = func(currentBalance, parameter);
}
```

```html
<input id="balance" value="0">
<div id="buttons">
  <button data-function="+" data-parameter="10">+10</button>
  <button data-function="+" data-parameter="100">+100</button>
  <button data-function="+" data-parameter="1000">+1k</button>
  <button data-function="*" data-parameter=".5">1/2 (разделить на 2)</button>
  <button data-function="*" data-parameter="2">x2 (умножить на 2)</button>
  <button data-function="=" data-parameter="3000">all (весь баланс (var balance))</button>
</div>
```

Comment: можете показать пример с данным решением?

Comment: @kiLLro добавил какой-то пример, не знаю, насколько он вам подходит